# ListView filter not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having problems with a listview filter, which I made from [this guide](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/).

In the guide the items are added via ".ItemsSource = list ", but I am adding my items by code(view.items.Add...)

My filter code looks like this:

```
osebe_listView.ItemsSource = list;

CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(osebe_listView.ItemsSource);


view.Filter = UserFilter;
```

filter:

```
private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(isci_tb.Text))
            return true;
        else
            return ((item as Oseba).nazivPodjetja.IndexOf(isci_tb.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }
```

isChanged filter textbox event:

```
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(osebe_listView.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

When I run the program, I am getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   ArduinoSMS_sender.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

I have no clue why I'm getting this error since I did bind my list to the listview as source.

EDIT: I found out why it wasnt working. I added items to listview before binding datasource, which isn't allowed. Because of that it didn't bind properly and returned the null reference exception.

Comment: Can you show the line error occured

Comment: Sure. http://prntscr.com/dz5fe8

Comment: I think your `view` has null value. `GetDefaultView()` returns null in your example. Can you look values of `view` and `UserFilter` objects and share with us

Comment: I am aware of that. Why is that so and how could I resolve this?